# pandas get_level_values for multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Is there a way to get the result of [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for more than one column?

Given the following `DataFrame`:

```
         d
a b c     
1 4 10  16
    11  17
  5 12  18
2 5 13  19
  6 14  20
3 7 15  21
```

I wish to get the values (*i.e.* list of tuples) of levels `a` and `c`:

```
[(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
```

**Notes:**

- It is impossible to give `get_level_values` more than one level (*e.g.* `df.index.get_level_values(['a','c']`)
- There's a workaround in which one could use `get_level_values` over each desired column and `zip` them together:

For example:

```
a_list = df.index.get_level_values('a').values
c_list = df.index.get_level_values('c').values

print([i for i in zip(a_list,c_list)])
[(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
```

but it get cumbersome as the number of columns grow.

- The code to build the example `DataFrame`:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'b':[4,4,5,5,6,7,],'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15], 'd':[16,17,18,19,20,21]}).set_index(['a','b','c'])`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.tolist()` method of a `MultiIndex` gives a list of tuples for all the levels in the `MultiIndex`. For example, with your example `DataFrame`,

```
df.index.tolist()
# => [(1, 4, 10), (1, 4, 11), (1, 5, 12), (2, 5, 13), (2, 6, 14), (3, 7, 15)]
```

So here are two ideas:

1. Get the list of tuples from the original `MultiIndex` and filter the result.

   ```
   [(a, c) for a, b, c in df.index.tolist()]
   # => [(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
   ```

   The disadvantage of this simple method is that you have you manually specify the order of the levels you want. You can leverage `itertools.compress` to select them by name instead.

   ```
   from itertools import compress

   mask = [1 if name in ['a', 'c'] else 0 for name in df.index.names]
   [tuple(compress(t, mask)) for t in df.index.tolist()]
   # => [(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
   ```
2. Create a MultiIndex that has exactly the levels you want and call `.tolist()` on it.

   ```
   df.index.droplevel('b').tolist()
   # => [(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
   ```

   If you would prefer to name the levels you want to keep — instead of those that you want to drop — you could do something like

   ```
   df.index.droplevel([level for level in df.index.names
                   if not level in ['a', 'c']]).tolist()
   # => [(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (3, 15)]
   ```

Comment: Nice use of `droplevel` in the last case :)

Answer (score 1):

This is less cumbersome insofar as you can pass the list of index names you want to select:

```
df.reset_index()[['a', 'c']].to_dict(orient='split')['data']
```

I have not found a way of selecting levels `'a'` and `'b'` from the index object directly, hence the use of `reset_index`.

Note that `to_dict` returns a list of lists and not tuples:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [2, 13], [2, 14], [3, 15]]
```

Comment: `reset_index` also allows you to specify the index levels e.g. `reset_index(level=['a', 'c'])` which may be faster (untested) if your index has many levels

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
df.index.to_frame().to_numpy()[:, [0,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the multi index to dataframe, then select the desired columns with labels or with location, then convert the sub dataframe to list of tuples with `to_records`.

```py
out = df.index.to_frame()[['a', 'c']].to_records(index=False)
# or
out = df.index.to_frame().iloc[:, [0, 2]].to_records(index=False)
```